# problem with urdfdom pkg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ros-indigo and try to catkin_make my workspace. Here is the result of catkin_make`

```
Base path: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit
Source space: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/src
Build space: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/build
Devel space: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/devel
Install space: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.19
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 26 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - moveit_planners (metapackage)
-- ~~  - moveit_plugins (metapackage)
-- ~~  - moveit_pr2 (metapackage)
-- ~~  - moveit_resources
-- ~~  - moveit_ros (metapackage)
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_config
-- ~~  - moveit_msgs
-- ~~  - moveit_core
-- ~~  - moveit_controller_manager_example
-- ~~  - moveit_fake_controller_manager
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_perception
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_planning
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_move_group
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_manipulation
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_robot_interaction
-- ~~  - moveit_simple_controller_manager
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_plugins
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_tests
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_warehouse
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_benchmarks
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_planning_interface
-- ~~  - moveit_commander
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_visualization
-- ~~  - moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui
-- ~~  - moveit_setup_assistant
-- ~~  - pr2_moveit_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'moveit_planners'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_planners/moveit_planners)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'moveit_plugins'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_plugins/moveit_plugins)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'moveit_pr2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_pr2/moveit_pr2)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'moveit_resources'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_resources)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'moveit_ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_ros/moveit_ros)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'pr2_moveit_config'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_pr2/pr2_moveit_config)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'moveit_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Generating .msg files for action moveit_msgs/MoveGroup /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/src/moveit_msgs/action/MoveGroup.action
-- Generating .msg files for action moveit_msgs/Pickup /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/src/moveit_msgs/action/Pickup.action
-- Generating .msg files for action moveit_msgs/Place /home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/src/moveit_msgs/action/Place.action
-- moveit_msgs: 59 messages, 12 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'moveit_core'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit_core)
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   date_time
--   thread
--   iostreams
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom" with any
  of the following names:

    urdfdomConfig.cmake
    urdfdom-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urdfdom" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urdfdom_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "urdfdom" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  moveit_core/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'urdfdom'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom" with any
  of the following names:

    urdfdomConfig.cmake
    urdfdom-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urdfdom" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urdfdom_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "urdfdom" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  moveit_core/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ruinianxu/ws_moveit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I checked some similar problems and I found there is no package.xml in my urdfdom folder. But I checked github and could only find package.xml file for hydro or groovy. Does that mean indigo don't need package.xml? I have no idea about how to solve this problem. Really appreciate if someone can help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261635/problem-with-urdfdom-pkg/) by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a problem with `urdfdom-pkg`, but with the way you've setup/initialised your workspace.

If you really *must* build MoveIt from source (as opposed to using the provided binaries, a `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit` away for supported platforms), please follow the appropriate instructions in the MoveIt documentation on how to [do a source install](http://moveit.ros.org/install/source/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2017-05-14**:
Here is my result of `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit`

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-indigo-moveit is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-14**:
So you already have MoveIt installed. Do you have a specific reason to want to build it from source again / still?

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2017-05-14**:
No. Just at the beginning I didn't know the difference between binary and source. Hence I installed both binary and source moveit. Problem is now even I delete the source file, there is still error about urdfdom-pkg.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-15**:
Ok. So you don't want to build moveit from sources any more?

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2017-05-15**:
actually I am ok with either. Just want a solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-15**:
I suggest you try and remove the `devel` and `build` directories from your catkin workspace (`rm -rf devel`, etc), remove the `moveit` source packages from the `src` space and then try building your workspace again.